# How does argparse determine argument names when dest is not used?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a questions about the `batch_size` argument used in the following example.

```
https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L150


parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=256, type=int,
                    metavar='N',
                    # dest='batch_size' why this is not needed? 
                    help='mini-batch size (default: 256), this is the total '
                         'batch size of all GPUs on the current node when '
                         'using Data Parallel or Distributed Data Parallel')

# missing code

args.batch_size = int(args.batch_size / ngpus_per_node)
```

My question is without the `dest` parameter, how can the `batch_size` be parsed and saved from command line?

Comment: It's a good idea to `print(args)` shortly after doing `args = parser.parse_args()`.  That will give you a clear idea of what the parser has done, including what `dest` if chose for each argument.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#dest:

> `ArgumentParser` generates the value of `dest` by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--` string
>   ...
>   Any internal `-` characters will be converted to `_` characters to make sure the string is a valid attribute name

In this case the `long-option` is `--batch-size`, so by default `dest` is set to `batch_size`